# How to check data of POST/PUT api method in Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

```html
data = request.get_json(force=True)
        print(data)
        emp = Employee.query.get(employee_id_to_update)
        print(emp.name)
        print(set(data.keys()))
        if 'dm' in data.keys() and logged_user.designation.lower() != "hr":
            return jsonify("You cannot perform this action")
        if data.get('name') :
            emp.name=data\['name'\]
        if data.get('email'):
            emp.name = data\['email'\]
        if data.get('gender'):
            emp.name = data\['gender'\]
```

I have tried this but i dont want multiple if statements , is there any way to replace if else statements

Comment: What do you plan to do if the user omitted those fields?  You can supply a default value to `data.get`, but is that sensible?  When you're doing data validation, you have lots of `if` statements like this.

Comment: yes there will be multiple if statements , but i am asking that is there any way to replace them or this only the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?  This is shorter, but I don't think this is any more readable:

```
    for field in ('name','email','gender'):
        if field in data:
            setattr( emp, field, data[field] )
```